# Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Each time I try to archive my application to submit it to apple Xcode keeps giving me this error! I'v Triple checked that in the Cocos2d libraries Target i made that my Install Group & Install Owner are correct and i;v restarted my computer & reinstalled Xcode. It runs just fine in the simulator. But like i said as soon as I hit Archive it gives me this error

```
SetOwnerAndGroup "Home:staff" "/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swimmu-bdswkmmaijgxvyasdnmkpmnfgxji/ArchiveIntermediates/Swimmu/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/usr/local/lib/libcocos2d libraries.a"
    cd /Users/Home/Documents/Swimmu
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/sbin/chown -RH "Home:staff" "/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swimmu-bdswkmmaijgxvyasdnmkpmnfgxji/ArchiveIntermediates/Swimmu/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/usr/local/lib/libcocos2d libraries.a"

chown: /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swimmu-bdswkmmaijgxvyasdnmkpmnfgxji/ArchiveIntermediates/Swimmu/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/usr/local/lib/libcocos2d libraries.a: No such file or directory
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"libcocos2d libraries.a"

The problem may be related to the space in the library. If you created that library target it should be easy to fix by changing the name of the library target to "cocos2d_libraries".

Comment: Thank you so much! I must have changed it on accident.

Answer (score 16):

Yet a third problem with the same error...  Different solution as well.  In my case, the default install group $(INSTALL_GROUP) was a windows domain and had \ in it, which translated to space and caused the build to fail.. I fixed it by changing my install group to be admin.

[image]

Comment: This has been an on-and-off issue for our Macs running on an Active Directory domain. Sometimes a reboot fixes it, but not this time.  Fortunately switching to the admin group worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your name entered in Install Owner should match the name of your Mac OS login under which you are logged in and the Name of Apple's Dev License and certificates.

So go to System Preferences | Users & Groups and set a Full name that matches your Apple's Developer License name

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem than you, but had the same error:

```
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

When I created my XCode project, my app name had a space in it, so trying to deploy my app always failed. I was able to fix this by using a `Custom Archive Name`.

In XCode 4...

1. Edit the Deployment Scheme
2. Click on the Archive tab
3. Then specify an Archive Name that doesn't have spaces in it.

[image: Specify a Custom Archive Name]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by cleaning the project, deleting derived data, and restarting Xcode.